# UWP Device Info File

Tags: uwp

I'm looking for the location / file that contains the definition for System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer -- is a property indicator that can access the property from within the properties bag of a DeviceInformation object. Now I cannot find where this defintion is done - and include in my project. Workring within C# - so looking for the .NET version.

so doing something like: 
var Man = RadioDevices[System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer];

but System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer is undefined and no indication of where it is located (that I can find -- there is a C++ header file that contains a def with this naming -- but need for .NET

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking closer at the contents of device information properties - realized that the collection is keyed on a string -- went through the collection - and it appears the key is the name associated to the property it relates to -- i.e. for manufacture property - you can access the property by doing the following

```
var Man = RadioDevices["System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer"];
```

- i.e. the name of the property explicilty as the key.

Note: if you want the manufacturer of a radio device - it may not exist - which is another question I have. So validation that the property exists should be done first.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties#device-properties) is  Device information property, it is not a namespace. If your want enumerate device, you need to use `DeviceWatcher` to capture device that match condition.

```
DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
    "", // AQS Filter string
    null, // requested properties
    deviceInfoKind);
```

And `System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer`  is often used to create Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) string. For example:

```
"System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\""
```

For more detail you could refer this code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).